# How do I stop an infinite loop from occurring while getting user input?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, infinite-loop

I'm a newbie writing a program that continues to ask the user for a number until the entered number is less than or equal to 100. I keep ending up in an infinite loop and I'm unsure of how to add the correct conditions to end the loop.

```
let num;

while (!(num === 100 && num < 99)) {     // infinite loop
    num = Number(prompt("Enter a number: "));
    console.log(num);
}
```

I want to exit the loop when the user enters a number less than or equal to 100.

Comment: How can a number equal 100 and be less than 99?

Comment: Since you are new, a great piece of advice is to avoid `while` loops for this very reason. Always have a test in the loop body that will serve as a back door to get out of the loop. In this case, you could give the user a finite amount of chances to enter a number and if they don't enter a valid value after that number of times, the loop exits. For that, you'd set up a counter variable and increment it at the end of the loop body. But, at the beginning of the loop body, you'd check to see if the counter has reached its limit. If so, `break` out of the loop.

Comment: "less than or equal to 100" you want `!(num <= 100)`

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks! I'm going to try again with a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue use either

```
!(num === 100 || num < 100)  or
!(num <= 100)
```

**Issue:** Num can never be both equal to 100 and less than 99 , so it will be false always and so while condition is true always

```js
let num; 
while (!(num <= 100)) { //or !(num === 100 || num < 100)
  num = Number(prompt("Enter a number: ")); 
  console.log(num); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let num = 101;
    
while (num > 100) {
   num = Number(prompt("Enter a number: "));
   console.log(num);
}
```

Or with Do/While:

```js
let num;
    
do {
   num = Number(prompt("Enter a number: "));
   console.log(num);
} while (num > 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let num;

while (true) {
    num = Number(prompt("Enter a number: "));
    if (num <= 100) {
     break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't create Fiddles or 3rd party solutions. Links die over time and make those unreachable. Executable code can be created right here in Stack Overflow. Also, your answer doesn't even include the link to the Fiddle.

Comment: will take care of it from next time.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for changing it to code snippet